# JSR330 DI vs. Spring DI

Tags: spring, guice

Why are people using Spring DI vs. JSR330 DI?  I see many projects still going forward at a huge speed with spring DI oblivious to the JSR330 specification.  Many don't even know it exists.  Was it not marketed enough and spring was?

I do see posts of Guice vs. spring, but the real argument should be JSR330 vs. spring since spring does not implement the spec yet(and hopefully one day it will).  Any ideas on why such a large portion of the community seems oblivious to JSR330 and not evolving to it?

NOTE: I should make a correction here.  Spring 3.0 does implement JSR330 and even has a way to override the default bindings much like guice except you have to supply an xml file instead of a Module file written in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring 3.X supports JSR-330 out fo the box - http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/java/springone-2gx-2011-summary/

It means that you can use the spring annotations or the JSR-330 ones.

Comment: HUH????  I don't see any use of {@javax.inject.Inject} anywhere nor of the other JSR330 annotations?? so I am very confused?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DeanHiller Take a look at the class  `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.  This class is used to autowire beans by looking for the valid autowire annotations.  You will notice in the constructor that they attempt to load the class using `ClassLoader.loadClass(String)`.

Comment: I finally found this article as well  http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/spring-3-0-and-jsr-330-part-2/ though I still am trying to get it to work now.

Comment: Everything worked great Provider, Inject, Singleton, EXCEPT "@Inject @Named("propertyName")" which did not seem to work :(.  maybe we have to change how properties are loaded.

Comment: @DeanHiller great! Sorry I can't help you on this one. Maybe it's worth another question in SO?

Comment: The Spring docs cover it in details: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations

Answer (score 4):

I would say it is because Spring is so much more than just a simple DI container.  Many teams use Spring for these other various reasons:

- Transaction Management
- Security
- MVC
- Aspects
- Data Access
- Batch processes
- Webflow
- Web Services
- [Many others...](http://www.springsource.org/features)

They have their hands in so many things that it just makes it easy mix and match Spring technologies to do general enterprise development.